# How to access properties in asp.net object coming from Deserialied json string

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have tried to use the DeserializeObject function in c# to convert the string to an object which works fine but the only problem rely on accessing the properties within that object such as job Description. How can I do this

My Json String

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "jobId": 39621555,
      "employerId": 391063,
      "employerName": "Opus Recruitment Solutions Ltd",
      "employerProfileId": null,
      "employerProfileName": null,
      "jobTitle": "iOS Developer",
      "locationName": "London",
      "minimumSalary": 500,
      "maximumSalary": 550,
      "currency": "GBP",
      "expirationDate": "10/01/2020",
      "date": "27/12/2019",
      "jobDescription": "iOS Developer&nbsp;&#163;500 - &#163;550I have partnered with a large financial organisation based in Central London who are looking for a iOS Developer to join their application development team for their 2020 project as part of a 6 month contract. You will be collaborating with a group of highly  skilled developers to implement the latest features for their well established app.&nbsp;Required skills:<b... ",
      "applications": 2,
      "jobUrl": "https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/ios-developer/39621555"
    }
  ],
  "ambiguousLocations": [],
  "totalResults": 9007
}
```

Attempted solution:

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(strtest);
ViewBag.Message = json.jobDescription;

public class Result
{
    public int jobId { get; set; }
    public int employerId { get; set; }
    public string employerName { get; set; }
    public object employerProfileId { get; set; }
    public object employerProfileName { get; set; }
    public string jobTitle { get; set; }
    public string locationName { get; set; }
    public int? minimumSalary { get; set; }
    public int? maximumSalary { get; set; }
    public string currency { get; set; }
    public string expirationDate { get; set; }
    public string date { get; set; }
    public string jobDescription { get; set; }
    public int applications { get; set; }
    public string jobUrl { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public List<object> ambiguousLocations { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It's index based in the `results` list. `ViewBag.Message = json.results[i].jobDescription;`

Comment: how to loop through all items in the view section

Comment: json.Count; is not working for instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just this!

```
 var obj= JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(strtest);

forEach(var item in obj.results ){
var jd=item.jobDescription;
}
```

if your result string is not a list change it in this way

```
{
  "results":
    {
      "jobId": 39621555,
      "employerId": 391063,
      "employerName": "Opus Recruitment Solutions Ltd",
      "employerProfileId": null,
      "employerProfileName": null,
      "jobTitle": "iOS Developer",
      "locationName": "London",
      "minimumSalary": 500,
      "maximumSalary": 550,
      "currency": "GBP",
      "expirationDate": "10/01/2020",
      "date": "27/12/2019",
      "jobDescription": "iOS Developer&nbsp;&#163;500 - &#163;550I have partnered with a large financial organisation based in Central London who are looking for a iOS Developer to join their application development team for their 2020 project as part of a 6 month contract. You will be collaborating with a group of highly  skilled developers to implement the latest features for their well established app.&nbsp;Required skills:<b... ",
      "applications": 2,
      "jobUrl": "https://www.reed.co.uk/jobs/ios-developer/39621555"
    }
  ,
  "ambiguousLocations": [],
  "totalResults": 9007
}
```

then deserialize it to following object

```
public class RootObject
{
    public Result results { get; set; }
    public List<object> ambiguousLocations { get; set; }
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
}
```

and pass it to view

```
   var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(strtest);

   ViewBag.Message = json.results.jobDescription;
```

Comment: `@foreach(var item in @ViewBag.Message)
{
<h3>@item.jobDescription;</h3>
}`